# Сравнение элементов, удовлетворяющих условию all/any

Tags: python

Как можно с помощью all/any со своим условием сравнить несколько значений?
Например, есть список, состоящий из чисел. И есть условие, что числа больше 10(i > 1- for i in список). Как узнать какое количество элементов удовлетворяет этому, используя all/any?

Возможно, следует сделать так, но нет ли более короткого и правильного кода:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]  # например
counter = 0
for i in a:
    if all(x > 10 for x in a):
        counter += 1
    else:
        counter -= 1
```

Comment: какой язык-то?? питон, штоле? Используя all/any  эту задачу решить нельзя. Можно, конечно, просто вставить и all и any  в код, но как-нибудь так, чтобы они не мешали эту задачу решать. Формально будет с использванием all/any

Comment: Если нужно просто посчитать количество элементов удовлетворяющих условию, просто оставьте условие `if i > 10`. Не понятно, зачем вам вдруг all/any тут захотелось применить.

Comment: код в вопросе не понял. А по тексту выходит это видимо `sum(1 for i in a if i > 10)`

Answer (score 1):

С использованием `all` :

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
counter = 0
for i in a:
    if all([i > 10]):
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Вывод:

```
5
```

Comment: тут можно, кстати, all и на any заменить :D Двух зайцев, ткскзть. Хочешь - через all, хочешь - через any 